# Encoded image sent over redis from Cpp app to Rust app, Invalid UTF-8- TypeError

Tags: c++, rust, redis, utf-8

I'm sending an encoded `cv` image over `redis pubsub` from `Cpp` app:

```
cv::Mat output_image;
output_image = cv::Mat(pic_height, pic_width * 2, CV_8UC3);
cv::imwrite(filename, output_image);
std::vector<uchar> encoded_image;
cv::imencode(".png", output_image, encoded_image);
std::string image_str(encoded_image.begin(), encoded_image.end());
string image_msg;
image_msg = to_string(pic_id) + "~" + metadata + "~" + image_str;
RedisCommunicator::GetInstance()->Publish(image_channel, image_msg);
```

I'm receiving the image in `Rust` app using `redis-rs`:

```
let mut redis_pubsub = redis_connection.as_pubsub();

redis_pubsub.subscribe(image_channel).expect("Failed to subscribe to channel");
info!("subscribed to channel: {}", image_channel);

redis_pubsub.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_secs(5))).expect("Failed to set read timeout");

for _ in 0..3 {
    info!("###### Waiting for message...");
    let log = match redis_pubsub.get_message(){
        Ok(T) => T,
        Err(e) => {info!("Failed to get message: {}", e); continue;},
    };
    let payload : String = match log.get_payload() {
        Ok(T) => T,
        Err(e) => {info!("Failed to get payload: {}", e);continue;},
    };
    if log_enabled!(Level::Debug) {
        debug!("Got log from channel: '{}', log: {}", log.get_channel_name(), payload);
    }
    info!("{{\"{}\": {}}}", image_channel, payload);
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
};
```

I'm receiving a format error in `Rust`. Logs:

```
[rusty_record] subscribed to channel: image_sender
[rusty_record] ###### Waiting for message...
[rusty_record] Failed to get payload: Invalid UTF-8- TypeError
[rusty_record] ###### Waiting for message...
[rusty_record] Failed to get payload: Invalid UTF-8- TypeError
[rusty_record] ###### Waiting for message...
[rusty_record] Failed to get payload: Invalid UTF-8- TypeError
```

Looking at `redis-cli`, there are messages in the `pubsub` channel:

```
redis-cli subscribe image_sender

1) "message"
2) "image_sender"
3) "3707~{\"pic_gain\":0,\"pic_exposure\":0,\"pic_time\":0,\"camera_id\":0,\"latitude\":0.000000,\"longitude\":0.000000,\"altitude\":0.000000,\"heading_degrees\":0.000000,\"auto_white_balance\":true}~\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x02\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x04\x03\x02\x02\x02\x02\x05\x04\x04\x03\x04\x06\x05\x06\x06\x06\x05\x06\x06\x06\a\t\b\x06\a\t\a\x06\x06\b\x0b\b\t\n\n\n\n\n\x06\b\x0b\x0c\x0b\n\x0c\t\n\n\n\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x05\x03\x03\x05\n\a\x06\a\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\xff\xc0\x00\x11\b\x00\xc0\x05\xa0\x03\x01\"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\b\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\a\"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\b#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\...
```

#### If I send a regular string it works fine.

Cpp:

```
string image_msg;
image_msg = to_string(pic_id) + "~" + metadata + "~" + "image_str";
RedisCommunicator::GetInstance()->Publish(image_channel, image_msg);
```

I'm receiving the messages in `Rust`. Logs:

```
[rusty_record] subscribed to channel: image_sender
[rusty_record] ###### Waiting for message...
[rusty_record] Got log from channel: 'image_handler_0', log: 7812~{"pic_gain":0,"pic_exposure":0,"pic_time":0,"camera_id":0,"latitude":0.000000,"longitude":0.000000,"altitude":0.000000,"heading_degrees":0.000000,"auto_white_balance":true}~image_str
[rusty_record] {"image_sender": 7812~{"pic_gain":0,"pic_exposure":0,"pic_time":0,"camera_id":0,"latitude":0.000000,"longitude":0.000000,"altitude":0.000000,"heading_degrees":0.000000,"auto_white_balance":true}~image_str}
[rusty_record] ###### Waiting for message...
[rusty_record] Got log from channel: 'image_handler_0', log: 7813~{"pic_gain":0,"pic_exposure":0,"pic_time":0,"camera_id":0,"latitude":0.000000,"longitude":0.000000,"altitude":0.000000,"heading_degrees":0.000000,"auto_white_balance":true}~image_str
[rusty_record] {"image_sender": 7813~{"pic_gain":0,"pic_exposure":0,"pic_time":0,"camera_id":0,"latitude":0.000000,"longitude":0.000000,"altitude":0.000000,"heading_degrees":0.000000,"auto_white_balance":true}~image_str}
[rusty_record] ###### Waiting for message...
[rusty_record] Got log from channel: 'image_handler_0', log: 7814~{"pic_gain":0,"pic_exposure":0,"pic_time":0,"camera_id":0,"latitude":0.000000,"longitude":0.000000,"altitude":0.000000,"heading_degrees":0.000000,"auto_white_balance":true}~image_str
[rusty_record] {"image_sender": 7814~{"pic_gain":0,"pic_exposure":0,"pic_time":0,"camera_id":0,"latitude":0.000000,"longitude":0.000000,"altitude":0.000000,"heading_degrees":0.000000,"auto_white_balance":true}~image_str}
```

** Still new to `Rust` please forgive me if there are some newbie mistakes.

Comment: I wonder if `imencode` is just dumping straight binary data into the string. If so you may need an extra step like base64 encoding that output so it is suitable to use as text.

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja , Looks like [imencode](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) compresses the image and stores it in the memory buffer.

Comment: `String`s in Rust are expected to be UTF-8 encoded _text_. You should use `Vec<u8>` for binary data like your images.

Comment: *of course* OpenCV's imencode gives you straight binary data, that you could dump into a file. there's no reason it should additionally turn that into hex or base64. none at all.  -- redis can do binary data. send binary data, not a string. strings are not binary data. https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/triggers-and-functions/concepts/binary_data/

Comment: Ok, so if I understand the fact that in the message there is text data- image number, and metadata separated by `~` delimiter is a problem when combined with binary data. if I use `Vec<u8>` for the payload, is there a way to parse the message with the delimiter?

Comment: If you use `Vec<u8>` for the payload, you can use [`splitn (2, '~')`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.splitn) to split the message, then [`str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) to convert the text fields to strings.

Comment: Thank you @Jmb , you solved my problem with `Vec<u8>`, `splitn (3, '~')`, and `str::from_utf8`. Can you write this as an answer or should I write the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String`s in Rust are expected to be UTF-8 encoded *text*. You should use `Vec<u8>` for binary data like your images. Most "string" manipulation functions also exist for byte slices `&[u8]`, and types that dereference to byte slices like `Vec<u8>`, so you can parse a `Vec<u8>` as easily as a `String` (using e.g. [`splitn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.splitn)) and convert the parts that contain text with [`str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html):

```
let mut redis_pubsub = redis_connection.as_pubsub();

redis_pubsub.subscribe(image_channel).expect("Failed to subscribe to channel");
info!("subscribed to channel: {}", image_channel);

redis_pubsub.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_secs(5))).expect("Failed to set read timeout");

for _ in 0..3 {
    info!("###### Waiting for message...");
    let log = match redis_pubsub.get_message(){
        Ok(T) => T,
        Err(e) => {info!("Failed to get message: {}", e); continue;},
    };
    let payload : Vec<u8> = match log.get_payload() {
        Ok(T) => T,
        Err(e) => {info!("Failed to get payload: {}", e);continue;},
    };
    if log_enabled!(Level::Debug) {
        debug!("Got log from channel: '{}', log: {}", log.get_channel_name(), payload);
    }
    let parts: Vec<_> = payload.splitn (3, |&c| c == b'~').collect();

    info!("id: {:?}", str::from_utf8 (parts[0]));
    info!("metadata: {:?}", str::from_utf8 (parts[1]));
    info!("data: {:?}", parts[2]);
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
};
```

Comment: I think it should be `splitn (3, |&c| c == b'~')` because `n` is the [number of  items](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.splitn:~:text=over%20subslices%20separated%20by%20elements%20that%20match%20pred%2C-,limited%20to%20returning%20at%20most%20n%20items,-.%20The%20matched%20element%20is%20not%20contained%20in%20the%20subslices)

Comment: @lior.i you're right, edited.